# awk convert ASCII to integer in context of awk command

Tags: awk, ascii, printf

I want to do some manipulation on a file with values coded by ASCII symbols.

I have a test file that looks something like this:

```
a>
b!
```

I would like to use an awk script to to convert them to integer values and then do further manipulation. I've looked and found a method of converting ASCII to integer:

```
for(n=0;n<256;n++)chr[n]=sprintf("%c",n)
```

but I don't know how to pass my integer values from this array to another array wherein I want to do my numeric manipulation.

Example output would be:

```
195
95
```

I can get it to work if I use a test file like this (without incorporation of the above code):

```
11
22
```

and the code:

```
cat testfile.txt | awk 'BEGIN {FS=""} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) ar[i]=ar[i]+$i} 
END {for(y=1;y<=length(ar);y++) print ar[y]}'
```

I get the desired result:

```
3
3
```

Does anyone have suggestions for how to convert the ASCII into an integer and then pass it to the rest of my awk statement?

Comment: You want to translate character a to Value 97 and the '>' to value 62? Thats ugly in awk. Your for-loop generates an lookup for the invers problem. Would it be possible to do an 'od -t x1 inputfile' and then process the result with awk?

Comment: I cannot understand why you got `10.5 and 47.5` where did the `.5` come from? can you give an example input with both cases (char and number etc), and also attached with an output file, better with brief explanation?

Comment: @tue: I need the conversion to happen after I put the values into the array. If I convert a to 97 (for example) then 9 and 7 would be loaded separately into my array.

Kent: You're correct. It should have been 195 and 95. The program I copied output from averages them and I made a typo. It's fixed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS=""
    for(n=0;n<256;n++)ord[sprintf("%c",n)]=n
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) ar[i]=ar[i]+ord[$i]
} 

END {
    for(y=1;y<=length(ar);y++) print ar[y]
}' file
```

Output:

```
195
95
```